# Feign Client Jackson serialization/deserialization issue with Spring Boot 3 native image

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, java-17, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I'm trying to build web app based on Spring Boot 3 and planning to run this in Kubernetes as native images.  So my goal is to build native image, but it is where I got issue with Feign here.

My app is using Feign client to access third party API.

Application works perfect when run as plain Java application in non-native mode. But once I'm running it as native image in Docker, it is unable to make third party calls because request/response DTO types are not available in native runtime, forcing Jackson to throw error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `com.steam.trading.trade.bot.client.steam.dto.SteamResponse`: cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator): this appears to be a native image, in which case you may need to configure reflection for the class that is to be deserialized
```

What I understand from this error is that AOT serialization hints are not created for Feign Client request/response dto data types. Also listing all classes for serialization is not an options, since it will be a lot of manual work to do and easy to miss something there.

Question is, is this some kind of bug in Open Feign, is there out of box `RuntimeHintsRegistrar` to import or should I register all DTO's by myself?

## **Project setup**

I'm using Spring Boot 3 and OpenFeign from Spring Cloud dependencies. Versions are:

```
    <spring-boot.version>3.0.4</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
```

I have following Feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "steam-server-time-api", url = "${app.steam.api}", configuration = FeignSteamConfiguration.class)
public interface ServerTimeClient {

    @RequestLine("POST /ITwoFactorService/QueryTime/v1/")
    SteamResponse<QueryTime> getServerTime();
}
```

And following Feign Configuration:

```
public class FeignSteamConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Contract useFeignAnnotations() {
        return new Contract.Default();
    }

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignFormEncoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters) {
        return new FormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
    }

    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder clientErrorDecoder() {
        return new CustomErrorDecoder();
    }
}
```

I tried Both default and Spring Contracts, but issue is the same.

I'm building images using command:

```
mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image
```

I tried to register manually, using RegisterReflectionForBinding, but having 50+ classes is not really good to manually list all of them.
Also I tried to switch Default and Spring contracts, but it issue is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries (like Jackson) that do serialization/deserialization of objects don't know how to do this in the spring native's runtime, so you should tell/register to spring native about the proxies classes, resource files/paths, reflected methods, or objects to serialize/deserialize.

So I believe that you'll need to create a class implementing the `RuntimeHintsRegistrar` interface and set up what are the classes that you'll need to serialize/deserialize, as described in this link:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.advanced.custom-hints (spring native custom hints)

or annotate in some config class this below annotation:
`@RegisterReflectionForBinding({YourCustomObject.class})`